# Парсинг первого элемента списка в dom

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, simple-html-dom

Есть разметка html на сайте:

```html
<div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__row ">
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">Нужное значение</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">
    <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__rank" style="background: rgba(7, 94, 157, 0.992157);">
      99
    </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col Free">0</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col Free">0</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">
    <label _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="control control_eye">
          <input _ngcontent-ovw-7="" name="result__checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

с помощью js хочу выбрать значение из нужного мне div/ Проблема в том что такой же класс есть и у других div

Вот мой код,

```
var p = [];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('table__col');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  p.push(elem[i].innerHTML);
  console.log(p[i]);
}
```

Как мне сделать чтобы выбирался только нужный мне 'table__col' он второй по очереди? Точнее не сам элемент, а то что внутри, его значение.

Update:

Указывать порядковый номер элемента не получается, прилетает в массив такая штука: Есть какой то способ спарсить значение из такой структуры html?

```
VM7477:5 нужное значение
VM7477:5 
    <div _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="table__rank" style="background: rgba(7, 94, 157, 0.811765);">
      81
    </div>

2VM7477:5 0
VM7477:5 
    <label _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="control control_eye">
      <input _ngcontent-scr-7="" name="result__checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <div _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

VM7477:5 нужное значение 2
VM7477:5 
    <div _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="table__rank" style="background: rgba(7, 94, 157, 0.980392);">
      98
    </div>

2VM7477:5 0
VM7477:5 
    <label _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="control control_eye">
      <input _ngcontent-scr-7="" name="result__checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <div _ngcontent-scr-7="" class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить доступ к нужному элементу по индексу:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div.table__row > div.table__col').textContent);
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__row ">
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">Нужное значение</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">
    <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__rank" style="background: rgba(7, 94, 157, 0.992157);">
      99
    </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col Free">0</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col Free">0</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__col">
    <label _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="control control_eye">
          <input _ngcontent-ovw-7="" name="result__checkbox" type="checkbox">
          <div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: обновил депозит, так не получается

Comment: а где там это нужное значение "2"?

Comment: а дальше идет точно такой же блок `<div _ngcontent-ovw-7="" class="table__row ">` и внутри опять повторяется структура как я показал в коде

Comment: @spectre_it приношу извинения, не сразу понял о чём речь. Правил код, проверьте.